# How to display date in different formats in ng-repeat - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a date as "2017-04-03 05:00:07". I need to check for the date is today's date. If it is today's date i need to display as today or time.

If it is yesterday's need to display as yesterday or date as "MMM dd"

If it is last month or with in this year then, "MMM dd".

If it is last year then dd/mm/yyyy

I tried to display like this using a directive but this is not working for me.

Is there anyother way?

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($filter) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        myDirective: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var date1 = new Date(scope.myDirective.updateddate);
        var date2 = new Date();
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        if (diffDays == 1) {
            scope.myDirective.updateddate = 'yesterday'
        } else if (diffDays > 2 && diffDays <= 365) {
            scope.myDirective.updateddate = $filter('date') scope.myDirective.updateddate, 'dd-MMM');
    }
    else if (diffDays > 365) {
        scope.myDirective.updateddate = $filter('date') scope.myDirective.updateddate, 'dd-MM-YYYY');
    } });
```

Comment: use custom filter

Answer (score 1):

Use Moment.js while displaying like

```
{{moment(date).calendar()}} // Today at 11:17 AM
```

For reference: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Have to agree with Shanky, moment is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) is the most correct approach to this.

You define a filter much like a directive:

```
app.filter('myfilternamehere', function() {
    return function(input) {
        //do some stuff that creates the correct output
        return output;
    }
});
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/34/) that might contain a solution for your problem and at the same time shows you how to create a custom directive in a bit more detail.

Comment: I need a directive which will automatically check for date and display related date format